# Real Scenarios for Nonauthoritative and Authoritative Restore

Tags: active-directory

I have read information about Non-authoritative and Authoritative Restore methods, but I don't understand the concepts and the real case scenarios about when to use them. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use an authoritative restore when you're restoring objects in AD to a previous state. i.e. Restoring a group to its previous state if someone accidentally deleted all of the members.

You use a non-authoritative restore when you don't want the AD database that you're restoring to replicate outbound. Since NTDS.DIT (the AD database) is restored as part of system state, if you need to do a system state restore on a DC but don't need to restore anything in AD, you would do a non-authoritative restore.